# Is there any danger of disconection with Database Key?

Tags: database, sqlite

Forgive my ignorance, I am a first day beginner with database conventions.

This is my SQLite code: (auto generated by my DB browser)

```
CREATE TABLE `ResearchItems` (
`ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`Name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`Description`   BLOB NOT NULL,
`PreReq1`   INTEGER,
`PreReq2`   INTEGER,
`PreReq3`   INTEGER);
```

I intend to manually insert an update data in the DB using a DB browser.
My intention is that the PreReq fields point to other items in the same DB. Obviously, once they are entered, I NEVER EVER want the connection to get broken unintentionally by me adding or removing entries. Is this guaranteed?

Also, is there some extra utility I can add to include some kind of data validation? Like a PreReq value should only be a currently existing key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds as if you want [foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

```
CREATE TABLE ResearchItems (
    ID          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name        TEXT NOT NULL,
    Description BLOB NOT NULL,
    PreReq1     INTEGER REFERENCES OtherTable(PreReqID),
    PreReq2     INTEGER REFERENCES OtherTable(PreReqID),
    PreReq3     INTEGER REFERENCES OtherTable(PreReqID)
);
```

Comment: "OtherTable" is the name of a table in the DB? and "PreReqID" is the name of a field in that table?

Comment: Read the documentation.